# Exclusive mouse/keyboard with the Winapi

Tags: c++, winapi, input, keyboard, mouse

DirectInput had an option to have exclusive mouse/keyboard access. I'm now moving away from using DirectInput and was wondering how I could achieve the same behavior by just using the winapi?

Edit: I guess I could just use SetCursorPos() to the middle of the window and hide the cursor via ShowCursor()

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: To prevent the mouse from going out of the window, which pauses my program.

Comment: even after pressing control atl del?

Comment: No, Ctrl alt del would still go through

Answer (score 2):

In the case of the mouse, use the Windows raw input API.

Use the flag RIDEV_CAPTUREMOUSE in your RAWINPUTDEVICE structure for the call to RegisterRawInputDevices. This will prevent mouse clicks from activating other windows. In combination with that, use the ShowCursor function to hide the mouse cursor. Those 2 things will reproduce the DirectInput exclusive mouse behavior. In its later revisions, DirectInput (for the keyboard and mouse) is just a wrapper around the raw input api.

I don't believe there is any equivalent control over the keyboard (and I don't think there was in DirectInput either.) However, this is generally not a problem since the user won't be able to get the input focus onto another app unless they specifically want to with alt-tab or ctrl-alt-dlt.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [SetCapture()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms646262%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

It would help if your question were clearer. A lack of mouse input (ie WM_MOUSEMOVE messages) to an app is generally something the app is robust to. After all, a perfectly stationary mouse won't generate any such messages. So I'm guessing that you're doing something a little unusual.

There is also a mechanism for tracking the mouse leaving your app's window(s) - see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms645615%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It involves setting up a TrackMouseEvent structure which is a little painful but it does all seem to work in my experience. I'm wondering if in fact it is this mechanism which is pausing your app?

Can't help much more than that on the info provided I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ClipCursor()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648383.aspx) to confine the mouse within a specific rectangle of the screen, such as the rectangle of your window.